# Calculate transform-origin based on element positioning

Tags: css, zooming, transform, css-transforms

I am trying to write an equation to re-calculate the transform-origin of a map when clicking on a particular key point using a combination of jQuery and the "transform-origin" CSS property.

To further clarify, I have a number of key points plotted on a map and would like to zoom into any given point by re-calculating the origin of my map based on the "left%" "top%" position coordinates of my key points.

My key points are absolutely positioned based on "left%" and "top%" and I am using the transform CSS property to scale the map x4 when clicking any given keypoint.

Any help figuring out this logic would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its related to this: [JavaScript Image zoom with CSS3 Transforms, How to calculate Origin? (with example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823513/javascript-image-zoom-with-css3-transforms-how-to-calculate-origin-with-examp?rq=1) have a look

<del>with an useful answer right here: http://doctype.com/javascript-image-zoom-css3-transforms-calculate-origin-example</del>